# Wordpress individual posts display gone wonky

Tags: wordpress, post

I have a very basic theme that I created and I'm running into a problem that I've never experienced with any other theme I've made.

The homepage, pages and blog category pages display fine. When I click on an individual blog post, though, the post appears at the TOP of the page, UNDER the header and nav bar.

http://s5.mynewsitereview.com/category/blog/ - this is correct

http://s5.mynewsitereview.com/test-post-one/#more-1 - this is not

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the page is scrolling (oddly, I agree) to your `more-1` anchor because you've specified that in your link (after the #).

I think you have two options:

1. Get rid of the anchor in your link (http://s5.mynewsitereview.com/test-post-one/ looks fine), or
2. Move (to the top of your post) or remove altogether the anchor (`<span id="more-1"></span>`)

Comment: I ended up finding out the problem on my own after much research - you hit it spot on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because `<div id="main-pages">`

have style:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

EDIT:
There is one easy to implement [full height layout with header, footer and columns](http://www.couzinhub.com/files/ehc/ehc-fixed-full-height.html).